# Arrayformula to calculate sum for each entry in a list

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to automatically calculate the respective score of list of entries in a list. Basically I need something in the lines of "If letters in column F exist in column A, then sum for each entry in column A and if letter not found in F then return 0". It should be an array type of formula.

I tried both query function, which didn't work the way I wrote it, and arrayformula, but it doesn't give me sum per row.

```
=query(b3:g,"select sum (G) when F contains B group by B")
```

```
=arrayformula(sumifs(G4:G,B4:B,F4:F))
```

I know you can use a combination with mmult, but I don't know how to combine that with matching the column values for the letters in the list.

**The file is listed below and is structured as following.**
The score list in column A is fixed, and each month data in F-G column is posted, if the score is 0 for that month then the letter doesn't show up in the F column. I need an automatic way to calculate so I get the numbers in sheet 2.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eyyqNL-LKw5F4kdDnbAPzN28jc4kWKMCJ-GAkn2yoXg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MAP()` or `BYROW()` will do the trick. Try below formula-

```
=MAP(B3:B17,LAMBDA(x,SUMIFS(G3:G,F3:F,x)))
```

For `>300` use-

```
=MAP(B3:B17,LAMBDA(x,SUMIFS(G3:G,F3:F,x,G3:G,">300")))
```

To make your input reference dynamic can use `B3:INDEX(B3:B,COUNTA(B3:B))` as array argument or `MAP()` function. Try-

```
=MAP(B3:INDEX(B3:B,COUNTA(B3:B)),LAMBDA(x,SUMIFS(G3:G,F3:F,x)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I will definitely check more about MAP() or BYROW() for future use. I have two questions regarding your reply. What does lambda do here? I tried entering it in c4 of the sheet "What I have", but my results seems to be skewed one row. How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: Actually MAP is helper function of LAMBDA. LAMBDA has few other helper functions like BYROW, BYCOL, REDUCE, SCAN, MAKEARRAY etc. LAMBDA can also use individually but that is for different purpose, specially to create custom functions. So, here lambda is mandatory to use with helper functions. Do a little search on google about lambda in excel.

Comment: Also, if it helps then please accept the answer (tick mark it).

Comment: Thank you so much. I tick marked the answer